# Thread or class error c++11

Tags: c++

when I try to compile the following code with `g++ -std=c++11 -pthread` I get the following error and have no idea why.

```
#include<thread>
using namespace std;
void test (){
}

int main () {
    thread t1 (test);
    t1.join;
    return 0;
}
```

> 8:9: error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function
>     t1.join;

Comment: If you try `t1.join()` do you get the same error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the parenthesis in the call to `join`:

```
t1.join();
//     ^^
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67b6b48f0c8e51f7)

Comment: OK, that would do it.  Tested and your fix works well.